# Error on gRPC tools installation

Tags: python, grpc

While I tried to install gRPC tools (in Python), I came up with error like this:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqyVK.png)

Could anyone tell me how to fix it? (OS:Mac OS X 10.9.5)

Comment: Do you tried with this? [gRPC install](http://www.grpc.io/blog/installation)

Comment: Yes, I did, I got no problem with installing gRPC, while during the installation of gRPC tools, following the instruction of http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html, which specifically is when executing the command '$ python -m pip install grpcio-tools' did I encounter this error. :(

Comment: With what version of `pip` are you working? If it's less than 9.0.0, are you able to reproduce the problem with `pip` 9.0.0 or later?

Comment: Result of running pip --version                                                                          pip 9.0.1from/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 /site-packages (python 2.7)